# Write from Serial Port to SD card

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to write from the Serial Port to an SD Card in my Arduino Mega 2560, using a card module.

I want to be able to write in a txt file what I type in the serial com.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

const int chipSelect = 4;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("This is a test and should be ignored");
   if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("\nCard failed, or not present");
    // don't do anything more:
    return;
  }
  else{
  Serial.println("\ncard initialized.");
}
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly
File OpenFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if(OpenFile and Serial.available());
  {
    OpenFile.println(Serial1.read());
    OpenFile.close();
  }
}
```

However a continous line of "-1" and "1", without the ", is written to the SD.

Yes, I am able to write to the SD card through other methods...

Cheers, PoP

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are checking `Serial.available()` but using Serial**1** to read from :)

As you have a Mega, you wouldn't get an error as there is `Serial` and `Serial1`. I'd say this is your culprit!

The `Stream` read function will return -1 when there is no data. Also you could lessen the load on your Arduino and do the operation all at once (not open/close for each byte) and purge all available data (`Serial.read()` only reads a single byte in case you did not know).

```
void loop() {

  File OpenFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  if(OpenFile){
    while(Serial.available()){
      OpenFile.println(Serial.read());
    }
    OpenFile.close();
  }
}
```

You may want to check if the SD lib supports appending by default or a flag like `FILE_APPEND` as you will overwrite the file on the next loop if more data becomes available (Serial data isn't instant, your code may loop while receiving the rest of the data).

Comment: It worked! But it was in ASCII (Code is on the other comp...). If anyone needs help in the future, you have to parse Serial.read with char :)

Comment: @PoP If the answer helped solve your question, could you consider adding a vote, or selecting it as the answer. Cheers